# Is there any grammatical mistake in "web designers and developers required?" 

Tags: grammaticality

I am going to publish the requirements of some local developers, however, someone said that there is a grammatical issue in following sentence: "web designers and developers required." Is there?

Comment: Who said that, I'll kick his ass?

Comment: Thanks Sam, advertisement have been published and just ensuring that I haven't made any mistake

Comment: The only mistake I can see is that the first letter should be capitalised; presumably this was done in the published version?

Comment: ["Staff Required!"](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22staff+required%22&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&biw=1920&bih=1057)

Comment: @Waggers first letter was capitalised and also published as title.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment they exactly said about verb as waggers said but yes I used these words as title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a *title*, "Web designers and developers required." is fine (although I would captialise the W, as I have done here). However as a *sentence* you would require a verb:

> Web designers and developers *are* required

or

> [Organisation name] *requires* web developers.

Answer (score 3):

It's actually a little unclear what you're asking for.  I'm guessing this is for an employment advertisement? “Web designers and developers required” is not really a requirement for the job. It's clearly what *you* require, but a requirement for a developer job would typically be something like, 3-5 years of experience, fluent in php, good interpersonal skills (I love that one, and they always include it for some reason) that sort of thing.

The heading for the ad might be, “Web designers and developers required” (although I think “needed” would be more typical).